# How to get columns name in mysqldb with a Python 2.7?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

If I am using select * from query it is working well, but when I am trying to query the columns name too, it isnt working (maybe because I have got a column called "FROM" but that's why i used 'FROM!?)

Here my code:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='admin',
    passwd='',
    db='database1',
    use_unicode=True,
    charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ select ACTUAL_TIME, 'FROM, ID
    union all
    select ACTUAL_TIME,  FROM , ID
    from TEST
        into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
        fields terminated by ';'
        enclosed by '"'
        lines terminated by '\n';
        """

cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

I get this error message:

```
raise errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'ACTUAL_TIME' in 'field list'")
```

EDIT: SHOW CREATE TABLE TEST;

```
| TEST | CREATE TABLE `TEST` (
  `ACTUAL_TIME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FROM` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=76287 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: use `backtick` \` around column names in `select` statements and then execute

Comment: The error message implies there's a problem separate from the one you're asking about. What does this `TEST` table look like? `SHOW CREATE TABLE TEST\G`

Comment: I updated my code with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='admin',
    passwd='',
    db='database1',
    use_unicode=True,
    charset="utf8")
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = """ select 'ACTUAL_TIME', 'FROM', 'ID' -- add single quotes
    union all
    select `ACTUAL_TIME`, `FROM`, `ID`  -- add here backtick in column names
    from TEST
        into outfile '/tmp/test.csv'
        fields terminated by ';'
        enclosed by '"'
        lines terminated by '\n';
        """

cursor.execute(query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

or else you can use this to get column names "SHOW columns"

or :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0")
print cursor.description
```

Comment: you are using ' " ' as enclosed by  have you tried with this too ?
Check the coloumn value names again incase of case sensitive.

Comment: I tried with your code, but the error message is the same. I checked the columns names it is sure its correct.

Comment: after my cursor.execute(query) part?

Comment: print [columns[0] for column in cursor.fetchall()]
NameError: name 'columns' is not defined

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 0")
print cursor.description
can you try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158942/discussion-between-rebecca21-and-harley).

Comment: @Rebecca21 Please wrap all the column names in the first line of the query in single quotes :)

Comment: @Rebecca21 I mean `query = """ select 'ACTUAL_TIME', 'FROM', 'ID' union all select \`ACTUAL_TIME\`, \`FROM\`, \`ID\` ...`

Comment: added the comment

Answer (score 0):

columns = cursor.description

result = [{columns[index][0]:column for index, column in enumerate(value)} for value in cursor.fetchall()]

print(result)

Comment: Would you mind to add some explanation for the not-so-experienced?