# Trying to dynamically get column names of select query

Tags: python, mysql

I'd like to be able to get the column names of my query back from the database so I can then use it to dynamically set the column length and name of my gui table.

So far after establishing a connection I've tried:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.callproc('db1.load_table', args)
for r in mycursor.stored_results():
    result = r.fetchall()
column_names = mycursor.column_names
```

I've also tried using `mycursor.description`

It didn't work.

What's the right approach here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get a list of column names from a psycopg2 cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252247/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-column-names-from-a-psycopg2-cursor) and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281931/how-to-get-columns-name-in-mysqldb-with-a-python-2-7/62993856

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you can :

```
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in mycursor.description]
```

Comment: I tried this -  this is what I got `['@_db1.load_table_arg1']` as column names. I'm using Microsoft Azure's MySQL service, not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: @danielajj what is your proc returning ,seems like its returning a scalar variable called `load_table_arg1`

Comment: `mycursor.stored_results` returns a tuple of data from the database after running the stored procedure